# Karel Robot: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, karel

I run this command to compile, it runs successfully:

```
javac -d . -cp .;KarelJRobot.jar StairClimber.java
```

Then I use this to try and run my class:

```
java -d –cp .;KarelJRobot.jar StairClimber
```

and I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ûcp
```

This is the entire class file:

```
import kareltherobot.*;

public class StairClimber {
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {   
        /* You fill this in */
        World.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I got the Karel Simulator from here:

```
http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/KJRDistribution060110.zip
```

Comment: If you get rid of all the "karel" stuff and just `System.out.println("hello world")`, does it still fail?

Comment: Yes it works fine without the Karel code but I have to remove karel out of the compile and run command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
java -d –cp .;KarelJRobot.jar StairClimber
--------^
```

Your cp argument hyphen is wrong. You need the `-` one next to `0` on your (US) keyboard. Do not copypaste the command from some PDF file or website. Enter the command all yourself.

```
java -d -cp .;KarelJRobot.jar StairClimber
```

Comment: +1 nice catch. I totally missed the significance of the "ûcp" :\

Comment: I wish I could +1 you man, thanks so much.  It was from a PDF.  I copy and pasted from it.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope that you'll stop copypasting code. Getting it out of your own fingers will end up it to be better remembered and practiced. Seriously.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below  (also, `:` instead of `;`) :

`java -cp .:KarelJRobot.jar StairClimber`

Comment: That would not have resulted in this error (how else would you explain it? and also that he successfully compiled it?). The colon is specific to *nix environments by the way. The semicolon is perfectly valid on windows environments.